# Is it possible to have browser specific fonts?

Tags: css, google-chrome, asp.net-core, firefox, fonts

I have a web application that is using the Quicksand Font. It looks fine in a Chrome browser, but with Firefox and Microsoft Edge it doesn't look very good with any character that has a thin edge like a D, P, R, or T.

[Example with capitalized D Firefox](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BKLV0.png)

[Example with capitalized D Chrome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tnI9D.png)

So I'm wondering the best way to have a browser specific font instead of having separate CSS files per browser. Unless I'm misunderstanding something and that is in fact the best way to do it.

Answer (score 0):

First you need to know your browser context (you can do it yourself or select a package, based on how detailed the agent report needs to be). Then:

> Component approach

In case you use a CSS in JS library (styledComponents, JSS, ...) it is very easy. You just have to query your browser context and have a wrapper element around your app that will be setting the proper fonts with some sort of general selector like the `*`.

> VanillaJS approach

Have every font in a single stylesheet (maybe in something like a global stylesheet or one that is particularly only for the fonts) and change the `<body />`'s class based on your context.